# How to add a file to current repo from another repo

Tags: git, github

Newbee to git. I have a cloned repo where I am working on. The cloned repo name is ABC and the branch name I am using is test.

So I am cloning the repo by:

```
git clone -b test git@github.com:myusername/abc.git abc_latest
```

And now, I found a file in another repo that I can just put into my repo and it works without any changes. Let say it is under username "otherusername" and repo name "DEF". Of course, I can clone the other repo by:

```
git clone git@github.com:otherusername/def.git def_latest
```

And the file I want to have is:

```
def/script/test.pl
```

My questions is, what is best way for me to use that test.pl file in my own repo/branch? Shall I create a link ? (how), shall I do a merge for that file only? (how)

Comment: Can't you just move or copy the file into your repository?

Answer (score 2):

I am taking your question at face value and hence assuming you are not talking about managing a sub-repository here.

> what is best way for me to use that test.pl file in my own repo/branch?

If it is literally just a single file which you want to take now, then just copy it into your repository like usual (cut&paste, `cp`, whatever), paying attention to copyright issues of course.

> Shall I create a link ? (how)

A file system link? Better not. This is in theory possible, but then you force every developer to use a common multi-repo directory layout; not a good idea generally.

> shall I do a merge for that file only? (how)

git merges commits, not files, so this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

[AnoE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38569596/4233593) is probably what you want, but since it is such an obvious solution, I'm gonna take a gander and assume that you do want the repositories integrated somehow. So here's a solution that uses only git commands and one local repository.

Clone your main project

```
git clone -b test git@github.com:myusername/abc.git abc_latest
cd abc_latest
```

Add the remote to second repo

```
git remote add def_latest git@github.com:otherusername/def.git
git fetch def_latest
```

Checkout the file from the other repo, say from its master branch

```
git checkout def_latest/master -- def/script/test.pl
```